# Emploi: « à rien » vs « de rien »

Tags: prépositions, de, à

> Ça ne sert de rien.
>
> Ça ne sert à rien.

Quand faut-il employer la première variante et quand la seconde ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La deuxième est quasiment la seule forme utilisée en français contemporain.

[image]

Elle répond à la question :

> *A quoi ça sert ?*

La première forme répond à la question :

> *De quoi ça sert ?*

qui n'est plus idiomatique en dehors éventuellement d'une langue écrite très soutenue, mais la question serait alors plutôt :

> *De quoi cela sert-il ?*

La forme *ne sert de rien* n'est donc plus utilisée à l'oral mais peut se rencontrer à l'écrit, bien qu'elle soit en déclin prononcé.

[image]

Il ne semble pas y avoir de consensus sur la différence entre les deux formes.

Certains ouvrages comme la Grammaire des grammaires (Girault-Duvivier, 1844) donnent à la forme avec *de* un sens plus fort que la forme avec *à* :

> On a souvent demandé si l'on doit dire : « Cela ne sert *de rien*, cela ne sert *à rien*. — *À quoi sert il ?* ou *de quoi sert il ?* »
>
> Ce qui ne sert de rien ne peut être employé utilement, est hors de tout service, d'une nullité absolue : « Par reconnaissance il nourrit un vieux cheval qui ne lui *sert de rien*. » — « Ce domestique est infirme il ne me *sert* plus *de rien*. » — « Nous eûmes beau pleurer nos larmes *ne servaient de rien*. » (Florian.)
>
> Mais enfin mes efforts ne me *servent de rien*.
>       (Racine, Britannicus, acte II, sc. 3)
>
> ll met toute sa gloire et son souverain bien
>   À grossir un trésor qui ne lui *sert de rien*
>   Plus il le voit accru moins il en fait d'usage.
>       (Boileau, Satire IV.)
>
> « Les murmures contre les décrets de la Providence *ne servent de rien*. »
>
> Toutes ces phrases éveillent l'idée d'une nullité absolue de service. Ce qui ne sert à rien aujourd'hui peut servir demain à quelque chose. « Il a des talents qui ne lui servent à rien. » — « Vous pouvez prendre mon cheval car il ne me sert à rien aujourd'hui. » Ici il y a une nullité momentanée de service, un défaut d'emploi.
>
> Fénelon (*Télémaque*, liv. V) a dans le même sens préféré *à* à *de* dans cette phrase : « *A quoi sert*-il à un peuple que son roi subjugue d'autres nations si l'on est malheureux sous son règne ? » Et Corneille :
>
> *A quoi* me *servirait* cette vie importune ?

Cependant, la plupart des autres ouvrages considèrent les deux expressions comme équivalentes.

Le Dictionnaire des pièges et difficultés de la langue française (Bordas, Jean Girodet, 2008) donne comme justification des deux formes l'euphonie par évitement de répétitions avec comme exemples :

> Il ne *sert **à** rien **de*** se lamenter.
>
> Ce livre *ne sert **de** rien **à*** un ignorant.

Grevisse (Le bon usage) indique que le verbe servir s'utilise avec *à* mais que *de* est encore parfois utilisé dans la langue écrite et note que la recommandation d'alternance *de - à* ou *à - de* n'est pas toujours respectée:

> *Il ne sert **de** rien **de** se mettre à rire.* (Gide, *Journal*, 26 décembre 1921)

En conclusion, je recommanderais de toujours utiliser la deuxième variante, la première étant trop archaïque pour ne pas être prise pour une faute de français.

Comment: ça dépend également si on pense à la musique d'Edith Piaf "Non, je ne regrette rien" avec le fameux "rien de rien" :P

Comment: @damadam Le *de* de *rien de rien* est un marqueur de superlatif que l'on retrouve dans *le saint des saints*, *l'as des as*, *vrai de vrai*, et autres expressions du même type. Il n'a absolument rien à voir avec le *de* que l'on peut rencontrer dans l'expression *servir de rien*.

Answer (score 1):

évite d'utiliser la 1ère forme, elle ne peut être utiliser que pour faire une comparaison (dans de rare cas), par exemple : 
"J'ai gagné la partie de rien" (pour dire que son point gagné était limite perdu avec un adversaire)

Ou alors, tu as aussi l'expression "De rien" équivalente au "No problem" en anglais

Comment: Je suppose que tu pensais à *j'ai gagn**é** la partie **d'un** rien*...

Comment: @jlliagre habituellement, j'utiliserais "de peu", mais "de rien" me semble plus naturel que "d'un rien" vu que la préposition "de" illustre mieux l'écart que "d'un" (et oups pour la faute d'accord)

Comment: *J'ai gagné la partie de rien* est effectivement une expression possible en français parlé assez relâché (*il a gagné de rien du tout*) mais elle n'a pas grand chose à voir avec *ça ne sert de rien* qui s'appuie au contraire sur une forme de français très littéraire.